# Prove that $[K : aHa^{-1} \cap K]$ is equal to number of left cosets of $H$ in $KaH$, where $K, H$ are subgroups of $G$ and $a\in G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism

Prove that $[K : aHa^{-1} \cap K]$ is equal to number of left cosets of $H$ in $KaH$, where $K, H$ are subgroups of $G$ and $a\in G$.

My work:

If we use $g \in G$, such that $gH$ is left coset, $gH$ will be an element of $KaH$ if $g \in Ka$. From the second theorem of isomorphism, we have the following: $K / K \cap aHa^{-1} \cong KaHa^{-1} / aHa^{-1}$. If we prove that $gH \cong KaHa^{-1} / aHa^{-1}$ we will have what we need.

Let $l \in KaHa^{-1}$. That means $l$ can be presented as $l = k \cdot h$ where $k \in K$, $h \in aHa^{-1}$. Then, $laHa^{-1} \in KaHa^{-1} / aHa^{-1}$ is equivalent to $kaHa^{-1}$. So, every element in $ KaHa^{-1} / aHa^{-1}$ has form of $kaHa^{-1}$. Now we have to prove that that is isomorphic to $gH$.

Let $\phi : KaH \to KaHa^{-1}$ be defined as $\phi(kah) = kaha^{-1}$, where $a$ is fixed element. $\phi$ is an isomorphism, which implies requested.

Can someone please tell me if this proof is correct? If not, what is incorrect?

Comment: You seem to have a typo in the title. Instead of $\cup$, it should be $\cap$.

Comment: I am not sure if your proof is correct (I did not read the details) but it is certainly too long. You can use the definition of cosets directly to prove your claim, so it takes only a few lines.

Comment: @kabenyuk yes, thanks, I edited it. What about correctness?

Comment: A word of warning. You cannot apply the second isomorphism theorem here, as this requires a normal subgroup somewhere. So you cannot write an isomorphism $K / K \cap aHa^{-1} \cong KaHa^{-1} / aHa^{-1}$. Still, in any case you have equality of indices $\lvert K : K \cap aHa^{-1} \rvert = \lvert KaHa^{-1} : aHa^{-1} \rvert$, and you can try and proceed from there.

Answer (score -2):

The elements $k_1,\ldots,k_t\in K$ are coset representatives for $aHa^{-1}\cap K = H_a$ in $K$ if and only if the elements $k_1a,\ldots,k_ta$ are representatives for the left $H$-cosets in $KaH$.

*Proof*. First notice that $x,y\in K$ are in the same $H_a$ coset if and only if $x^{-1}y = aha^{-1} \in H_a$ if and only if $ya = xah$ for $h\in H$, if and only if the left cosets $xaH$ and $yaH$ coincide.

This proves that the index $[K:H_a]$ is equal to the number of left $H$-cosets appearing in $KaH$, which is what you wanted.